# Mix asp.net with Php login / registration form

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, sql-server-2008, data-migration

Am trying to convert a php website to asp.net but I am having an issue moving the already registered users(php/mysql) to asp.net since the passwords are salted in php.

I am planning on mixing the non-secured asp pages with the login and registration page in PHP, but am not sure how silly that might be.

Any Idea is highly welcomed!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against having a chimera application comprised of different scripting languages (PHP being opensource, and ASP being proprietery from Microsoft)

The main reason would be **Maintenance** as any subsequent changes to the application would have to be done by someone who knows both ASP and PHP. Documenting this would also be a nightmare as you would have to add specs for APIs between each technology etc.

What I would suggest is going the full measure and have ASP interfacing with MYSQL using its own libraries rather than relying on PHP as the middle man.

The effort you make at this moment will save you the headache down the road of the applications lifecycle.

Have a look at this article on MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479002.aspx

Comment: Thanks bruce for the link...I know how horrible it wud be to manage different tools especially when a proprietary is involved. I have managed to complete every other part of the project btu my challenge remains making it possible for users on the Old php site to access the new asp.net site, based on their login details in php/mysql...regards interfacing asp with mysql, i already have the login table with username and password(salted)...any clue on how to manage this??